# Using PublishSubject and flatMap to achieve concurrency

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to build an Android service where I have a list(`LIST`) of items and want to perform a task on each of those items (the task could be an upload or download task).

- When the tasks are in progress, more items can added to the LIST dynamically and items within the list may be re-arranged (if the items are not already processed yet).
- I am looking to process either `n` tasks concurrently at any time.

This is what I have tried after reading through different online sources; unfortunately it does not work.

```
val scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Pair<String, String>>()
publishSubject
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap({ it ->
        io.reactivex.Observable.fromCallable { it }
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .map { pair ->
                {
                    println("Op in progress")
                    SystemClock.sleep(4000) // simulate network operating and a heap of other operations
                }
            }
    }, 5 /* concurrency */)
    .subscribe()
```

To begin with, I have the list of items to process which are published as

```
LIST.forEach {
    publishSubject.onNext(it)
}
```

When I get additional items to process, I invoke

```
publishSubject.onNext(item)
```

From the logs, I can see that `publishSubject.onNext(item)` is invoked. But, `println("Op in progress")` is not invoked and I can see there are no corresponding log outputs.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATED** code snippet after incorporating the comments from @akarnokd

```
val scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Pair<String, String>>()
publishSubject
    .flatMap({ it ->
        io.reactivex.Observable.just(it)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .map { pair ->
                    println("Op in progress")
                    SystemClock.sleep(4000) // simulate network operating and a heap of other operations
            }
    }, 5 /* concurrency */)
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: What is `scheduler` actually? You may get an error you are not handling in `subscribe()`. Also `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` has no practical effect on a `Subject`. Plus, you can use `Observable.just(it)` instead of `fromCallable`.

Comment: You also don't seem to return anything from `map { pair -> }` which I don't know what defaults to, `null` or `Unit` in Kotlin.

Comment: I have updated the snippet; `scheduler` is just `Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))`

Comment: Why should `map { pair -> }` have to return anything? Isn't it block where the computation is done? Eventually, I will have code in it to trigger `publishSubject.onNext(item)`

Comment: I'm no Kotlin developer, but it might be possible `{ pair -> { } }` returns some implicit object/lambda and does nothing. Try without that inner `{ }`. Also `map` is for transformation which means you have to return a value for some input value.

Comment: Also how do you think you get parallelism of 5 with a threadpool of 1 thread?

Comment: I suspect it might be the extra braces you have around your println code. You're telling the system "given a pair, return a lambda that, when invoked, will print a line of text and then sleep. But of course you never invoke that lambda. (your subscribe method does nothing). You should remove the extra braces and see what happens.

Comment: I just noticed what @akarnokd said, and he is correct. We're both saying the same thing.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Yes, the issue was exactly what @akarnokd pointed out. Also, the threadpool size was `1` so that I could just get it to work.